# Yellow/Tan space around content in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

No buttons or backgrounds were in place when I had auto layout turned on, so I turned it off, and tested it on a 5s. It worked well, but on other models like the 6, it would show the contents in the size of the 5s screen, like so:

[image]

It wouldn't let me change any constraint settings.

So because it was acting like this, I turned autolayout back on, and then 
tried to clear out the yellow space by making the background and buttons larger and moving them. They just went behind the yellow space. I tried to add missing constraints,reset to suggested constraints, make background constrain to 0 on all sides, etc, nothings worked.

This is what it looks like now in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: What constraints have you set?  Do you have any red errors or orange warnings in the interface builder?

Comment: @Paulw11 Ive got an error `warning: Unsupported Configuration: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`
  but its always been there and ill fix it later. The background was set to have the 4 red bars in then button at the bottom set to 0, and the buttons I added the "missing constraints"

Comment: You are not setting constraints correctly.

Comment: Check your view's leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints. They don't seem to be 0 or perhaps you have also set width/height. Something is definitely wrong with your constraints